# Behaviour of Matlab fixed-point numbers with 1-bit

Tags: matlab, fixed-point

I noticed a funny behaviour with Matlab-FI numbers. It occurs only with 1-bit, signed numbers (a datatype that does not make a lot of sense in practice).
I'm aware that multiplying a double with a fi is not a good practice and the behaviour may even depend on the Matlab version, but I would expect the behaviour to be the same independent of the number of bits. This seems to be consistent in versions 2011b, 2013a and 2013b and I would like to understand why it happens that way.

**Example 1:** -1 can be representet as 1-bit, signed. However the result has a fraction-part of -2 which would allow only numbers [-8, -4, 0, 4]

```
>> a = fi(-1,1,1,0)
a = -1
      s1,0

>> 1*a
ans = 0
      s2,-2
```

**Example 2:** A 1-bit, unsigned behaves as expected, the fraction-part is unchanged

```
>> b = fi(1,0,1,0)
b = 1
      u1,0

>> 1*b
ans = 1
      u2,0
```

**Example 3:** A 2-bit, signed behaves as expected, the fraction-part is unchanged, the integer-part is extended

```
>> c = fi(-2,1,2,0)
c = -2
      s2,0

>> 1*c
ans = -2
      s4,0
```

**Example 4:** Another 1-bit, signed showing a similar behaviour as in example 1.

```
>> d = fi(-0.5,1,1,1)
d = -0.5000
      s1,1

>> 1*d
ans = 0
      s2,-1
```

Comment: Since that question didn't get any attention, I have crossposted to [Matlab Central](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/113278-behaviour-of-matlab-fixed-point-numbers-with-1-bit). I'll update here if I get any answers there.

Comment: Stepping though this operation we get into `mtimes.m` which in this case calls the `fimtimes(a,b)` function. I cannot step into this function to examine the code. Therefore to get an answer we will need someone from Mathworks to chime in. Otherwise, the best I can give is: this is a bug in `fimtimes` (and `fitimes`).

Comment: Also, I observe similar odd behavior with division.  With `a` defined as you have it in your first example I see `1/a = 0` and `a/1 = -1` but this second result gives a divide by zero warning!

Comment: Thanks @nguthrie for confirming the issue! I have also sent this question to Mathworks support directly.

Comment: Not sure if I understand what is going on, but my guess would be that you have insufficient word length leading to something like rounding errors?

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin: Well given the output type of e.g. Ex. 1, there is rounding involved and the result is "correctly rounded". However I don't understand why the output type is correctly expanded to represent the result in all cases except for 1-bit, signed arguments where rounding would not introduce an error.

Comment: Can't try myself, but does it matter whether you cast the 1 to `fi` before multiplication?

Comment: Yes it does matter. `fi(-1,1,1,0)*fi(1,0,1,0)`, `fi(-1,1,1,0)*fi(1,1,2,0)` and `fi(-1,1,1,0)*fi(-1,1,1,0)` all return correct values with correct sizes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When matlab is multiplying numbers with different format, it is changing the first of all modifying the formats. If you convert the `1` to the same format as your value, sometimes the number one in this format is `0`, so it makes sense that the product is zero, and everything is as expected.

**Example 1**

```
a = fi(-1,1,1,0); a_one = fi(1,1,1,0); disp([a, a_one, a*a_one])
    -1     0     0

          DataTypeMode: Fixed-point: binary point scaling
            Signedness: Signed
            WordLength: 1
        FractionLength: 0
```

**Example 2**

```
b = fi(1,0,1,0); b_one = fi(1,0,1,0); disp([b, b_one, b*b_one])
     1     1     1

          DataTypeMode: Fixed-point: binary point scaling
            Signedness: Unsigned
            WordLength: 1
        FractionLength: 0
```

**Example 3**

```
c = fi(-2,1,2,0); c_one = fi(1,1,2,0); disp([c, c_one, c*c_one])
    -2     1    -2

          DataTypeMode: Fixed-point: binary point scaling
            Signedness: Signed
            WordLength: 2
        FractionLength: 0
```

**Example 4**

```
d = fi(-0.5,1,1,1); d_one = fi(1,1,1,1); disp([d, d_one, d*d_one])
  -0.500000000000000                   0                   0

          DataTypeMode: Fixed-point: binary point scaling
            Signedness: Signed
            WordLength: 1
        FractionLength: 1
```

Comment: You are right that this may depend on the exact type that the double is converted to in the first place. I found also some more strange cases which are not 1-bit numbers, like `fi(2,0,2,0)*10` returning `24`... It would be interesting to find a way to know this intermediary type - can the debugger be used somehow to investigate that? However, what I don't like in your answer is that you output 3 variables of different types as a vector: Because a vector always has a single datatype and our problem is specifically about types, it would be better to print `d`, `d_one` and `d*d_one` separately.

Comment: +50 Since casting the double to the type of the other operand is really the key. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>**Disclaimer:** The following is the (slightly edited) answer from MathWorks support which I'm adding for completeness. In brief it turns out that this is not limited to 1-bit datatypes, but (as pointed out by sebas) to the double constant being cast to the other operand and saturating there, notably without warning, but according to spec.</sub>

---

It turns out that the double constant value (e.g., `1`) is cast to a FI type prior to the math operation (e.g. `*`), using the signedness and wordlength of the other operand. However, the new FI type uses a "best precision" fraction length instead of the fraction length of the other operand.

Here is some equivalent MATLAB code with the explicit `fi()` constructor illustrating this:

**Example 1.**

```
>> a = fi(-1,1,1,0)
a =
    -1
    s1,0

>> fi(1,a.SignednessBool,a.WordLength) * a
ans =
    0
    s2,-2

>> 1*a
ans =
    0
    s2,-2
```

**Example 2.**

```
>> b = fi(1,0,1,0)
b =
    1
    u1,0

>> fi(1,b.SignednessBool,b.WordLength) * b
ans =
    1
    u2,0

>> 1 * b
ans =
    1
    u2,0
```

**Example 3.**

```
>> c = fi(-2,1,2,0)
c =
    -2
    s2,0

>> fi(1,c.SignednessBool,c.WordLength) * c
ans =
    -2
    s4,0

>> 1 * c
ans =
    -2
    s4,0
```

**Example 4.**

```
>> d = fi(-0.5,1,1,1)
d =
    -0.5000
    s1,1

>> fi(1,d.SignednessBool,d.WordLength) * d
ans =
    0
    s2,-1

>> 1*d
ans =
    0
    s2,-1
```

I hope these examples help clarify the issue with the implicit type casting of a double constant value (e.g., `1`).